# Open Google Maps (or alternative) navigation with multiple destinations or waypoints

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, gps, maps

I'm working on a cross platform (iOS & Android) javascript app that requires the user to follow a path made of several destinations.

```
   <a href="geo:origin_Latitude,origin_Longitude?q=Destination_Latitude,
     Destination_Longitude">open map</a>
```

With this code when user click open map in my app it open google or yandex maps navigation gps app and start to navigation from origin coordinate to destination coordinate

Is there a way to navigation on multiple destinations in Google-yandex Maps?I want to navigate use from source location to destination 1,destination 2.....

Comment: Have a look at [Google Maps URLs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide#directions-action) documentation. You can open Google maps in directions or navigation mode and specify waypoints in the URL.

Comment: can you give me a url with multi waypoints please.I try all options.No one open navigation mode.Just <a href="geo.." open navigation but geo only support one destination in query string parametere

Answer (score 0):

Yes- it seems you can pass multiple waypoints into a Google Maps URL using pipes.  This is specified in the [Google Maps Developer Guide](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro#Waypoints) in the section about Waypoints.

Comment: But geo attribute does not support pipes.This not work  <a href="geo:41.9,28.9?q=41.1,28.1|41.5,28.5">open map</a>